# How to diagonalize a transformation from a $2\times 2$ matrix to a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Say $V = M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, and 
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}$$

How to find the eigenvalues of T and a ordered basis $B$ for $V$ that $[V]_B$ is a diagonal matrix?

My approach is to find the matrix representation of this transfromation, and find the characteristic polynomial. However, I am stuck in finding such a matrix representation.

I guess the matrix would be $4 \times 4$, but it does not make sense for $M_{4 \times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) = M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, if we follow the "definition" of a transformation matrix?

Comment: You should forget about the matrix structure of $V$, and treat it just as any 4-dimensional real vector space. In fact, perhaps it makes more sense to think of $V$ as $\mathbb R^4$. Using your notation, the "equation" $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb R) \times \mathbb R^4 = \mathbb R^4$ should make more sense. Edit: but, in this case, it might be easier to just *guess* four linearly independent eigenvectors, since the definition of $T$ is sufficiently simple that you could probably do that.

Comment: NB - in this particular case, things are simple enough for you to not even need much machinery - $ \begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ a & b \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\c & d  \end{bmatrix}$ immediately gives $\lambda = \pm 1$, since $a = \lambda c = \lambda ( \lambda a)$. Next just squinting at the problem a bit suggests the eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the corresponding ones with the first and second columns switched.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you, now I see $\lambda = \pm 1$. Can you explain a little bit more how to get the eigenvectors? My intuition stays at finding a kernel of $T - \lambda Id$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator $\;T\;$ simply changes rows, so;

$$\begin{pmatrix}c&d\\a&b\end{pmatrix}=\color{red}T\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\color{red}{\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, this operator's action on some basis (say the usual one) of $\;M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R)\;$ isw pretty simple:

$$\begin{align*}&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$

and thus

$$[T]=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This is a symmetric matrix and thus diagonalizable. Check it characteristic polynomial is

$$(x^2-1)^2=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2\;,\;\;\text{with eigenvalues}\;\;\pm1$$

each of geometric multiplicity two, and thus its JCF is

$$[T]_J=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&\!-1&0\\0&0&0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you! This answer helps a lot. So to find a matrix representation, I just need to think the result of $T(e_1) = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ as $ \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$, then put it as one column of $[T]$?

Comment: @JayWong Not exactly: you have to pick a basis, apply the operator to each vector in int and write each result as a linear combination of the basis, and then take the transpose of the coefficients matrix. In this particular case things are very simple...

Comment: Ok I see now. In this case $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1 &0\end{pmatrix} = 0e_1 + 0e_2 + 1e_3 + 0e_4$, so take the ranspose of those coefficients we then can get $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\1 \\0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JayWong Exactly...and again: in **this particular case** it doesn't matter the coefficients matrix or its transpose as that's a *symmetric* matrix.